# inheritance, necessity of __init__

Tags: python

The link below is really nice, it gives an example if inheritance without having to do that not-so-nice looking `Foo.__init_(...)` where `Foo` is a soon-to-be subclass of `class Bang`: `class Foo(Bang):...`

https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Question: What if I want to create some new variables inside my class, like `self._biz`? Must I then create an `__init__` method?

Comment: Like the name should suggest, the initializer initializes your object instances. If you want to add additional properties, then you should absolutely define the initializer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want to create instance variables, you should override `__init__` (and be sure to call the parent class's implementation, too).